# how to implement extraction of 2FA recovery codes to txt file

Tags: javascript, extract

I need to enable the user to extract (in txt or csv file) the 2 Factor Authentication codes.

The injected code where the 2fa codes generate in the html is:

```
@for (var row = 0; row < Model.RecoveryCodes.Length; row += 2)
{
<code class="recovery-code">@Model.RecoveryCodes[row]</code><text>&nbsp;</text><code class="recovery-code">@Model.RecoveryCodes[row + 1]</code><br />
}
```

that gives:

[Recovery Codes screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCuIn.png)

Is there a way to extract the codes data table?
Thanks in advance

I have tried classic extraction ways, with js, but they work only in textarea instances
eg

```
function download(filename, text) {
        var element = document.createElement('a');
        element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
        element.setAttribute('download', filename);

        element.style.display = 'none';
        document.body.appendChild(element);

        element.click();

        document.body.removeChild(element);
    }
```

Comment: I tried generating the codes one by one and add them into a hidden textarea field. Then export this field by classic js and it works.

Comment: <script>
        function download(filename, text) {
            var element = document.createElement('a');
            element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
            element.setAttribute('download', filename);

            element.style.display = 'none';
            document.body.appendChild(element);

            element.click();

            document.body.removeChild(element);
        }
    </script>

Comment: <form onsubmit="download(this['name'].value, this['text'].value)">
                    <input type="text" name="name" value="Recovery codes.txt">
                    <textarea hidden name="text">Recovery Codes:&#10;&#10;@Model.RecoveryCodes[0] &nbsp; @Model.RecoveryCodes[1]&#10;@Model.RecoveryCodes[2] &nbsp; @Model.RecoveryCodes[3]&#10;@Model.RecoveryCodes[4] &nbsp; @Model.RecoveryCodes[5]&#10;@Model.RecoveryCodes[6] &nbsp; @Model.RecoveryCodes[7]</textarea>
                    <input type="submit" value="Download">
                </form>

Comment: IDs need to be unique, a simple and basic rule that you are still violating by creating this content in a loop.

Comment: Why don't you just loop over all `.recovery-code` elements, and grab their text content?

Comment: 1. You are right, I edited and posted the original code (without ids).  2. Looping the recovering codes would create multiple textareas which was the problem of exporting in a single file at the first place.

Comment: Who said anything about "textareas"? You loop over the elements, you get their text content, you append that to a string variable. No textareas involved.